# Creating a Bloomberg bquant portfolio

Tags: portfolio, bloomberg, quants

As an ex-investment banker (salesperson to be specific) and amateur programmer, I’d like to move into quant work.

I’d like to create a coding portfolio using Bloomberg’s bquant, but as I’ve left the bank I don’t have access to a Bloomberg terminal anymore and I’ve lost all my scripts.

Do you know if an individual can get access to a Bloomberg terminal ?

Also, do you know if it would be ok from a copyright perspective for me to post my bquant python projects onto a website or GitHub or medium for example ?

Comment: BBG has the so called [stay connected](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/stayconnected/pre-register/) programme. It will not allow you to get access to anything on your previous login. If you need that, you would need to talk to your previous employer and get their permission to copy this data. Posting this stuff online will also require permission from your previous employer. My 2 cents, they will not allow that if it was useful.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply ! For any other person looking at this question : I’m going to re-create my scripts without bquant, just pure python (with financial / data packages of course). I cannot use bloomberg’s Stay Connected program as I’ve already left my previous employer. Also, as AKdemy suggests I probably won’t be able to make the old code available publicly anyhow. But next time, I will make sure to use the Stay Connected feature ahead of time! Great tip AKdemy